# Is it possible to add another graph 10 years to munin?

Tags: munin, graph

Is it possible to add a fifth graph (following after day, week, month, year), e.g. "10 years" to munin?
If yes, is it possible without losing the existing data/graphs?

Comment: Adding another graph: not possible, but you can change an existing one to 10 years: http://guide.munin-monitoring.org/en/latest/advanced/custom-rrd-sizing.html